Movie about a kid with a terrible illness (with many phases of body function losses)
I've been looking for this movie about a boy who gets a rare illness.
This illness starts when the boy is between 5-9 years old and is based on a real person's story. The illness has many symptoms involving the illness one by one. First the boy gets pains, then becomes blind, then deaf, then bald, etc.
It's a very good movie, but very horrid and disturbing at the same time (due to the illness, that is).
I remember the father of the boy to be a famous face, possibly James Woods or Nick Nolte. I've checked both their filmographies but couldn't find it.
Thanks to anyone who can give me any answers or hints!
